# How to read from one file and write to several other files

Tags: python, file

I have a file containing several images. The images are chopped up in packets, I called packet chunk in my code example. Every chunk contains a header with: count, uniqueID, start, length. Start contains the start index of the img_data within the chunk and length is the length of the img_data within the chunk. Count runs from 0 to 255 and the img_data of all these 256 chunks combined forms one image. Before reading the chunks I open a 'dummy.bin' file to have something to write to, otherwise I get that f is not defined. At the end I remove the 'dummy.bin' file. The problem is that I need a file reference to start with. Although this code works I wonder if there is another way then creating a dummy-file to get a file reference. The first chunk in 'test_file.bin' has hdr['count'] == 0 so f.close() will be called in the first iteration. That is why I need to have a file reference f before entering the for loop. Apart from that, every iteration I write img_data to a file with f.write(img_data), here I also need a file reference that needs to be defined prior to entering the for loop, in case the first chunk has hdr['count'] != 0. Is this the best solution? how do you generally read from a file and create several other files from it?

```
# read file, write several other files
import os

def read_chunks(filename, chunksize = 512):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunksize)
        if chunk:
            yield chunk
        else:
            break

def parse_header(data):
    count = data[0]
    uniqueID = data[1]
    start = data[2]
    length = data[3]
    return {'count': count, 'uniqueID': uniqueID, 'start': start, 'length': length}

filename = 'test_file.bin'
f = open('dummy.bin', 'wb')
for chunk in read_chunks(filename):
    hdr = parse_header(chunk)
    if hdr['count'] == 0:
        f.close()
        img_filename = 'img_' + str(hdr['uniqueID']) + '.raw'
        f = open(img_filename, 'wb')
    img_data = chunk[hdr['start']: hdr['start'] + hdr['length']]
    f.write(img_data)
print(type(f))
f.close()
os.remove('dummy.bin')
```

Comment: It is not clear what works or doesn't work with your sample code, or what problem you face exactly. Please add more detail so that we can help you.

Comment: I changed to problem description. thanks for any suggestions